# OO Solution for Using Single Method

Tags: java, oop

I will use Java as an example, but this question really applies across all OO languages:

Say I have several different tab types: Research, Info, and Help, for example.  These are all placed in a JTabbedPane as needed.  Which tabs will be needed varies.  When the user selects a tab containing the Research tab type, it needs to run `setStandards()`.  The other tab types need not do this.  This can be accomplished in two ways:

```
if (pane instanceof Research) {
   (Research)pane.setStandards();
}
```

or by implementing an empty `setStandards()` method in the Info/Help classes (or their parent).

The first method is ugly, but my question is, is it okay to have the empty method to allow `setStandards()` to be called on any tab opaquely even if it does nothing?  It just seems a bit silly to have this placeholder method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second approach is the better of the two, but even better would be to have a method called something like `tabSelected` or something similar. The Research tab's `tabSelected` method would call `setStandards`. The other tabs would do nothing in this method. That way it's a meaningful method, even though it does nothing in some of the classes.

Comment: Sounds good.  This is conceptually the same thing, it's just a bit cleaner in terms of naming conventions.  I was just wondering if there was a way around the concept entirely.

Comment: At a low-level they're the same, but code isn't just for communicating to computers, it's also for talking to future maintainers of that code (including yourself 6 months from now). Having high-level methods for "events" like "tabSelected" is a pretty common thing to do, and such a method probably wouldn't seem out of place in your base class, while "setStandards" probably would. If later you decide that your Help pane needs to load the help index you don't want to add "loadHelpIndex" to your base class, but adding it to Help and then calling it from Help's tabSelected method would be natural.

Comment: As for if there's a way around it entirely: something somewhere needs to make the decision. In OOP it's generally better to use polymorphic methods than instanceof (or equivalent) to choose between different behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

The `pane instanceof Research` is pretty clearly a Bad Idea, because it breaks encapsulation (the knowledge that only "Research" tabs implement "setStandards()" has leaked out into the calling class).

Probably a better approach is to define a generic "tabWasSelected()" method in the superclass for all your tabs (they do all inherit from a single parent, right :-), and then let each tab class implement whatever logic (such as "setStandards()") that needs to happen when it's selected.

Another model (in some OO languages at least) is to have the tabs optionally implement the method ("tabWasSelected()"), and only invoke it when it's implemented. In other words, instead of testing for class identity with "instanceof", you instead test whether the class implements the specified method. This is common with delegate methods in objective-C:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tabWasSelected)]) // if implemented
       [delegate tabWasSelected]; // invoke it
```

Comment: Good solution, but it's conceptually the same as implementing `setStandards()` in the parent, just that `tabWasSelected()` is a well-named wrapper for it.  I was wondering if this can be done with a different concept entirely.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do in this case is that I would define an interface such as `TabLifecycleActions` which would have methods like `onTabSelected()`, `onTabDeselected()` etc. and then implement a "*null*" version of these in the superclass. Then all I would have to do would be to wire the UI component to call correct methods at the right time and override the method's implementation in those subclasses which need some specific functionality at that point.